# FontAwesome fa-sticky-note-o not displaying in em html tag in Chrome on Chromebook

Tags: html, google-chrome, font-awesome

The fa-sticky-note-o icon is not being displayed in
`<em class="fa fa-sticky-note-o" aria-hidden="true"></em>` on my Chromebook, which is current.  Other icons, such as `<em class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></em>` are displayed. It does appear when expressed as `&#xf24a;`  Unfortunately, this is a major documentary feature on https://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html  I doubt that they are going to want to code their page differently just for my benefit.  :)

I looked at the source of the Marlin document when it became evident that something was missing.  I checked the FontAwesome cheatsheet `https://fontawesome.com/v4/cheatsheet/` and see that it is displayed when expressed as `&#xf24a;`  I was hoping to find how to update or define the icon, but didn't find anything that told me how to do that.  I see that "/assets/stylesheets/fontawesome.min.css" is part of the of the head.load javascript at top of the page.  Could that be corrupted somehow?  How would I force a reload?

Comment: `fa-sticky-note` seems to work, the non-outlined version. I see the following class definition in your CSS: `.fa-note-sticky:before,.fa-sticky-note:before{content:"\f249"}` It appears to be missing a class definition for the outlined version though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fontawsome.min.css` file appears to be missing a class definition for `.fa-note-stick-o`.

You'll want to add the following class definition(s) to it:

```
.fa-note-sticky-o:before,.fa-sticky-note-o:before{
    content:"\f24a";
}
```